# Mean-Shift sklearn K function

Tags: scikit-learn, mean-shift

I was trying to read the documentation on sklearn's MeanShift and saw this formula:

[image]

What is the K function? I couldn't find it on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K is Gaussian Kernel. You can see [this document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) about MeanShift. Also, if you want to have an Open Source Framework ([Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_MeanShift.htm)).